# How to get Fourier–Stieltjes transform on $\mathbb R$ from the nice function on $\mathbb T$ (periodic on $\mathbb R$)?

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis, representation-theory, fourier-series, harmonic-functions

We put, $M(\mathbb R)= $The set of bounded complex Borel measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R$ and for $\mu \in M(\mathbb R)$, we define $||\mu||:= |\mu| (\mathbb R) = \text {total variation of } \ \mu $; and 
 $$B(\mathbb R) := \{f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb C : \exists \ \mu \in M(\mathbb R) \  \text {such that} \ f(y) = \hat{\mu}(y)  \};$$
 where, 
 $\hat{\mu}(y)= \int_{\mathbb R} e^{-iyx} d\mu(y),$ and for $f\in B(\mathbb R)$, we define 
 $$||f||=||\hat{\mu}||:= ||\mu||.$$

**My Question** : Put, $\mathbb T:= \{z\in \mathbb C : |z|=1 \}$ and suppose $f$ is function on the circle $\mathbb T$ and its Fourier series is absolutely convergent, that is, $\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z}|\hat{f}(n)|< \infty$; where,  $\hat{f}(n)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t) e^{-int} dt, \ (n\in \mathbb Z)$;  ,  and it satisfies the property  $f(e^{i\theta})=0$ for $\pi-\delta \leq \theta \leq \pi + \delta $; ($0<\delta < \pi $).

Define $F:\mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ such that $$F(x):= f(e^{ix})$$ for every $x\in \mathbb R$.

> How to show that  $F\in B(\mathbb R)$; and $||F||= \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z}|\hat{f}(n)|$.

**My vague attempt**: To show $F\in B(\mathbb R)$, that is , by definition of $B(\mathbb R)$, I must show, there exists complex Borel $\mu$ on $\mathbb R$ such that, 
$$F(y)=\hat{\mu} (y)= \int_{\mathbb R} e^{-iyx} d\mu(x);$$
keeping this goal in mind, inversion formula suggests me that,  I should take, $\mu  $, such that, $ \int_{\mathbb R} e^{-iyx} d\mu(x) = \int_{\mathbb R}  e^{-ixy} \hat{F}(y) dy $
( the inversion formula valid provided $F, \hat{F} \in L^{1} (\mathbb R)$, and but here in our case  this may not be the case and this may be the real difficulties); If this is the case, then I guess, we can define, $\mu (E)=\mu_{F} (E)= \int_{E} \hat{F} (y) dy $, for Borel set $E$ and also I guess, $||\mu||= ||\hat{F}||_{L^{1}(\mathbb R)}$; but I really don't see be any connection between $||F||$ and $\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z}|\hat{f}(n)|$;

Thanks,

Comment: All that notation is not really necessary and $F$ is just the periodic extension of $f$, pulling back from $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. So $\|F\| = \| f\|$. So your question is really whether the Fourier transform is an isometry on your set, as a map of algebras. I don't see why that it should be. As a representation of the Banach algebra $l^1$, it's a contraction in general.